# Application logging framework in WinCE 7

Tags: logging, windows-ce, error-logging

We are in search of a logging framework/utility to be used with WinCE 7. Our programming language is C. We require circular logging to files in secondary storage, multi-thread safe logging, multiple threads going to read/write to a log file simultaneously etc. In other operating systems like Linux, we found utilities like Log4C, syslog etc to be useful. Similarly in QNX, there is a utility called slogger. 
We wonder if there is any similar utility/framework that could be used in WinCE 7 for ARM platform.

Thanks in advance, 
Lullaby

Answer (score 1):

If those libraries are in plain C or C++ using the fopen/fread/fwrite functions or C++ streams you may be able to port them to CE with a limited effort. If they also provided a Windows version that would make things easier. Just remember that CE is natively unicode so you may have to take care of some conversions.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this myself, but there is a [log4c-embed](https://code.google.com/p/log4c-embed/) project on code.google.com that claims to have ported log4c to WEH. Have you looked at that?

Comment: Yeah.. We have tried the same. But the project is not active now. The author claims it was built successfully in WinCE 5. But on putting an initial one day effort to try building the same for WinCE 7, we failed. Anyways, for some other reasons, we have switched to Linux. So the task is put on hold now.